# MSSQL: выбрать несколько последних записей

Tags: sql-server

В MSSQL лежит чуть больше десятка таблиц, последние 3 записи каждой из которых я хотел бы просмотреть. Первые три я выбираю запросом:

```
SELECT TOP 3 * FROM table_name;
```

Когда одно из полей содержит идентификатор-инкремент, *можно отсортировать данные по убыванию идентификатора* и опять же сделать запрос SELECT TOP...

Однако не во всех таблицах есть этот самый инкремент. Есть, к примеру, таблица, в которой всего два поля: [name] и [type].

Есть ли какой-нибудь вариант увидеть последние записи в этом случае?

UPD. Огорюсь, что для меня пока загадка, как MSSQL хранит данные. Я знаю, что данные писались в таблицы последовательно и предполагаю, что запрос SELECT TOP... выбирает *первые* (иными словами, *самые ранние из записанных в БД*) записи. Соответственно, меня интересуют *последние* записанные в таблицы данные.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Denis Khvorostin не думаю, что порядок добавления действительно гарантирован  в M$Sql. то что вам везло еще ничего не значит.

[тут эмоциональное рассследование поведения mssql на эту тему(eng)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/conor_cunningham_msft/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by)

Answer (score 2):

В общем случае - нет. Одна запись ничем не лучше другой, так что если нет identity или хотя бы даты или timestamp, то нет причин думать, что какая-то из них добавлена раньше.

Comment: У меня есть как минимум две причины думать. Первая: каждый раз при выполнении запроса SELECT TOP... я получаю одни и те же данные. Раз в запросе нет явной сортировки, возвращаются данные в порядке их попадания в БД. По идее, этот порядок как-то можно использовать. Вторая: я неоднократно писал данные в MySQL с последующим добавлением первичного ключа. Ни разу при этом данные не перемешивались. Первичный ключ фиксировал порядок записей.

Comment: Видимо ваш первичный ключ не был кластерным. А некластерный индекс записи не перемещает. Также, если вашей базе устроят сжатие, то порядок записей в таблице без кластерного ключа с большой вероятностью изменится. То же самое произойдет при восстановления из бэкапа и/или переезде на другую файловую группу.

Comment: Вообще, если очень нужно, а записей не очень много, можете сделать через xml, сформировав набор элементов по всем записи и выбрав те из них, которые удовлетворяют условию [position() > last() - 3] (если есть ключ, то лучше пихать в xml его, а потом использовать его же для получения остальных данных). Но это вернет просто три каких-то записи, которые с некоторой вероятностью являются последними.